# CWD ENOENT on run npm install

Tags: angular, npm-install

When I try to run `npm install` in my angular project I get following error

```
cwd = process.cwd();
              ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was because:

1. I have open terminal on directory `myporoject`
2. In separate terminal i rename dir `myproject` to `myprocject-copy` and
3. I `git clone` code to `myproject`
4. In first terminal I try to run `npm install`

Explanation: when I rename folder the first terminale detach from dir `myproject` and did not automagically attach to new folder `myproject` cloned from git. So the command `npm` lost ground under it's feet and show this error.

### Solution

To "repair" `npm install` in old terminal first type:

`cd ../myproject`